# pointer being realloc'd was not allocated

Tags: c, realloc

```
size_t writeFunctionHandler(char *contents,size_t size,size_t nmemb,void *userdata) {
  // size of the storedSize
  static size_t storedSize = 0;

  // the size of data available
  size_t realSize = size * nmemb;

  char *dataBuffer = (char *) userdata;

  // realloc the buffer buffer
  dataBuffer = realloc(dataBuffer,storedSize + realSize);

  if (dataBuffer == NULL) {
    printf("Could not allocate memory \n");
    return 0;
  }

  // store the contents of realSize from last storedSize
  memcpy(&(dataBuffer[storedSize]),contents,realSize);

  storedSize += realSize;
  return realSize;
}
```

I fail to understand as to why the above code return and error **pointer being realloc'd was not allocated**

And when I used this sample code

```
struct MemoryStruct {
  char *memory;
};

size_t writeFunctionHandler(char *contents,size_t size,size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
  size_t realSize = size * nmemb;
  static size_t storedSize = 0;
  //char *dataBuffer = (char *)userdata;
  struct MemoryStruct *chunk = (struct MemoryStruct *)userdata;

  printf("print 1\n");
  chunk -> memory = realloc(chunk -> memory,storedSize + realSize);
  printf("print 2\n");

  if (chunk -> memory == NULL) {
    printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
    return 0;
  }

  memcpy(&(chunk -> memory[storedSize]),contents,realSize);
  storedSize += realSize;
  printf("print 3\n");

  return realSize;
}
```

All seem to work properly fine.

This above is a curl **writeFunctionHandler**

```
int main() {
   char *buffer = calloc(1,1);
   // struct MemoryStruct chunk;
   // chunk.memory = calloc(1,1);

   CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://stackoverflow.com");
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeFunctionHandler);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)buffer);
   // curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *) &chunk);

   free(buffer);
   //free(chunk.memory);
   curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

   return 0;
}
```

I fail to understand what difference between the 2 code except the fact that I'm using `struct` in the later case.

Comment: Are you sure the **sample** function doesn't have anything between the last `curl_easy_setopt` and `free(chunk.memory)`?

Comment: @StoryTeller Here how the actual code look like https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9274da0998124dc9576f28e52327af87

Comment: Sorry, but the link you gave is just a 404

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9274da0998124dc9576f28e52327af87

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: I see the code you posted doesn't have a call to `curl_easy_perform`. So I don't see when your callback can be executed, exactly. A [mcve] please.

Comment: @StoryTeller https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html as soon as the CURL has data to write it calls the callback.

Comment: @StoryTeller https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9274da0998124dc9576f28e52327af87#file-curl_easy-c-L55

Comment: Well `buffer` and `chunk-> memory` are 2 different example As I have mention earlier

Comment: @SouravGhosh `char *dataBuffer = userdata;` use this instead of casting it correct.

Comment: Oh, `dataBuffer = realloc(dataBuffer,storedSize + realSize);` That modifies a *local* variable. The original `userdata` pointer is unchanged. So next time your handler is called it will get the old `userdata` value not the `realloced` value.

Comment: @kaylum I was assuming the same but how does it work with the struct example. I you can provide insight on that also that would be really helpful.

Comment: `chunk->memory` is not a local variable. It is the same variable each time the handler is called. Which will work just fine as you have found.

Comment: Well in case of `chunk->memory` `userdata` is a pointer to struct `MemoryStruct`. In case of `buffer` `userdata` is a pointer to `char buffer` both of which are created in main. So what the differences.

Comment: Well, the differences is that the first example reallocates `userdata` each time. In the second example, `userdata` is unchanged. IN the first example, the `realloc` invalidates `userdata`. So it is a garbage pointer the next time the handler is called. In the second example, the `realloc` invalidates the old `chunk->memory` pointer but that is fine as it is correctly replaced with the new `realloc` value.

Comment: @kaylum - You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @kaylum what do you mean by userdata is unchanged.

Comment: In the second example, `userdata` is set to `&chunk`. That values remains valid throughout the execution of the program.  In the first example, `userdata` is set to `buffer`. But that becomes invalid on the first realloc (which frees the original `buffer` memory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that `userdata` points to  struct containing a member `memory` and it is that member that is alloced from the heap.

Further, when the function returns, then `memory` may have been changed with the realloc, but in your version the change cannot be seen outside the function. That is because the *value* of the pointer was passed, not the *address*. If the address were passed (i.e. `void **userdata`), you would have realloced to that address (i.e. `*userdata= realloc(..`) and it would have become visible outside the function.